# set permission with vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to give permission to everyone to a folder call Test. if i do this it works

```
objShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe","/k icacls c:\Test /grant everyone:(OI)(CI)M ", "",
```

but if i do this it doesn't

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Dim var
  var = "C:\Test"
  objShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k icacls" & var & "/grant everyone:(OI)(CI)M ", "",  "runas", 1
```

so my question is how can i make it work
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your spaces, incluide them in your variable like

```
var = " C:\Test "
```

or better pre- and append them to the rest of the string

```
objShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k icacls " & var & " /grant everyone:(OI)(CI)M ", "",  "runas", 1
```

Comment: When inserting variables into command strings it's also a good idea to add quotes, e.g. `"..." & Chr(34) & var & Chr(34) & "..."`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a spacing issue. Can you please try this?

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Dim var
  var = "C:\test"
  objShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", " /k icacls " & var & " /grant everyone:(OI)(CI)M ", "",  " runas ", 1
```